# Rock ID: Dark, Hard, Midland Valley Scotland

Tags: geology

Found this in a river. The dark part is the rock still drying out. I think the smoothness is the weathering from the river. The rock is heavy and a little bit rough on the underside among the smoothness. I noticed it because it set my metal detecting pin pointer off and it is magnetic. Not sure what the brown/orange stuff is. Hardness is defo 5.5 as it scratches glass.

Found in a carboniferous zone and other deposits nearby are quartz and limestone.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a piece of weathered Hematite to me, hardness, weight, fit but I don't believe hematite is strongly magnetic, how magnetic is the piece?  A similar mineral is magnetite, I have collected magnetite near hydrothermally altered limestone.  Magnetite is strongly magnetic, a voice coil magnet, ie out of a harddrive, will be hard to remove from a piece of magnetite.  If you don't get better responses try following the guide found here.  https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions/125#125

Comment: Thanks for that and you are correct I mistyped should have been metallic as magents are attracted to it - thanks for the answer  :)